# Django: saving model instance from function inside class based view not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

TLDR: I am probably doing something wrong.  I am attempting to update and save a record from a function (get_context_data) inside a class based view (generic.UpdateView). I have read so many diffrent things I am confused and stuck.

Please forgive me if I am doing something sub optimal.  I am newish to Django and cannot find any examples of what I am attempting to do. I presume I am doing something foolish that could be done much easier in another way or what I am attempting is an edge case.  I have already tried a bunch of things and this seems to work and prints out all the information to the console, it is just not saving.  Please forgive the code gore.

OVERVIEW: I have a model (**Record**) that, amongst other things tracks the **Stage** of work for the a work order. A **Record** tracks it's **Stage** via a FoerignKey relationship.  When a **Record** is saved I am using **signals** to check if the **Stage** value has changed, and if so track it in another model (**RecordStageChange**).  I need to also record the time difference between the each **Record**'s entry on the **RecordStageChange** table and the previous.

**MODELS**

```
class Record(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Customer', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="company")
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        'Status',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        default="3"
    )
    stage = models.ForeignKey(
        'Stage',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        default="3"
    )
    ***OTHER FIELDS OMMITED FOR SPACE***


class Stage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique=True, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RecordStageChange(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey('Record', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    stage = models.ForeignKey('Stage', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    previous_stage = models.ForeignKey(
        'Stage',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="previous_stage",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    change_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    change_delta = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s > %s' % (self.record, self.previous_stage, self.stage)
```

**VIEW**

```
class RecordUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "records/record_update.html"
    form_class = RecordModelForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        # user = self.request.user
        queryset = Record.objects.all()
        # self.calculate_time_delta()
        return queryset


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.object
        notes = Notes.objects.filter(record=pk).order_by('-noteDateTime')
        stages = RecordStageChange.objects.filter(
            record=pk).order_by('-change_datetime')
        labtotals = LabTotal.objects.filter(
            record=pk).order_by('-added_datetime')
        context["notes"] = notes
        context["stages"] = stages
        context["labtotals"] = labtotals

        n = 0
        for each in stages:
            print(f'START: {stages[n]}    {stages[n].change_datetime} Delta: {stages[n].change_delta}')

            if n > 0:
                delta = stages[n-1].change_datetime - stages[n].change_datetime
                print(f'{stages[n]}    {stages[n].change_datetime}  for:  {delta}')
                # print(f'{stages[n].change_delta}')
                if not stages[n].change_delta:
                    print(f'inside:{stages[n]} {stages[n].change_delta}')
                    stages[n].change_delta = delta
                    stages[n].save
                    print(stages[n], stages[n].change_delta)
            n += 1

        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("records:record_list")
```

GOALS: 1. Figure out why this isn't saving when it seems like it is.  2. Receive kindly advise or suggestions on a better methodology.

**Additional Information**
The print statements are just for me to try and figure out what is happening though the console.  Part of the reason I am attempting to piggy back on the get_context_data is that it is an easy way to execute the code again my refreshing and ensuring that no calculations were missed when fetching the data.

**Sample Console Output**

```
START: WO2420000 Work-Complete > In-Shipping    2021-02-24 18:13:10.314641+00:00 Delta: None
START: WO2420000 On-Bench > Work-Complete    2021-02-15 17:27:57.482281+00:00 Delta: None
WO2420000 On-Bench > Work-Complete    2021-02-15 17:27:57.482281+00:00  for:  9 days, 0:45:12.832360
inside:WO2420000 On-Bench > Work-Complete None
WO2420000 On-Bench > Work-Complete 9 days, 0:45:12.832360
START: WO2420000 In-Lab > On-Bench    2021-02-11 00:25:41.817291+00:00 Delta: None
WO2420000 In-Lab > On-Bench    2021-02-11 00:25:41.817291+00:00  for:  4 days, 17:02:15.664990
inside:WO2420000 In-Lab > On-Bench None
WO2420000 In-Lab > On-Bench 4 days, 17:02:15.664990
START: WO2420000 Components-Confirmed > In-Lab    2021-02-11 00:02:27.739079+00:00 Delta: None
WO2420000 Components-Confirmed > In-Lab    2021-02-11 00:02:27.739079+00:00  for:  0:23:14.078212
inside:WO2420000 Components-Confirmed > In-Lab None
WO2420000 Components-Confirmed > In-Lab 0:23:14.078212
START: WO2420000 None > Components-Confirmed    2021-02-10 23:08:21.628713+00:00 Delta: None
WO2420000 None > Components-Confirmed    2021-02-10 23:08:21.628713+00:00  for:  0:54:06.110366
inside:WO2420000 None > Components-Confirmed None
WO2420000 None > Components-Confirmed 0:54:06.110366
START: WO2420000 None > Picking    2021-02-10 22:33:30.869360+00:00 Delta: None
WO2420000 None > Picking    2021-02-10 22:33:30.869360+00:00  for:  0:34:50.759353
inside:WO2420000 None > Picking None
WO2420000 None > Picking 0:34:50.759353
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Do this kind of thing in your signals. Don't abuse methods of generic class based views. Make sure to use a [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) for recording timedelta.

I got it now. It was a combination of 3 issues. I will document it below in the event it may help someone in the future.

1. `.save` and `.save()` are not the same.
2. Piggy backing on `get_context_data` is dumb. Don't do it.
3. I needed to use a [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) rather than a DateTimeField in the model.

Moving it into the signal which is truly the best place to put it since it will do the calculation when adding an entry to the RecordStageChange model/database table is the obvious place to put it. I am not sure what I was thinking. I am pretty sure I had been too close to it for too long and really needed to step back.

Finally in the event someone may benefit from the code of the working signal...

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Record)
def record_fields_if_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        print('except sender.DoesNotExist')
        RecordStatusChange.objects.create(
            record=instance,
            status=instance.status,
            previous_status=None,
            user=instance.user,
        )
    else:
        if not obj.status == instance.status:  # Field has changed
            print(f" {instance.user} : {obj.status} > {instance.status} ")
            RecordStatusChange.objects.create(
                record=instance,
                status=instance.status,
                previous_status=obj.status,
                user=instance.user,
            )
        if not obj.stage == instance.stage:  # Field has changed
            print(f" {instance.user} : {obj.stage} > {instance.stage} ")
            RecordStageChange.objects.create(
                record=instance,
                stage=instance.stage,
                previous_stage=obj.stage,
                user=instance.user,
            )
    finally:
        stages = RecordStageChange.objects.filter(record=obj).order_by('-change_datetime')

        n = 0
        for each in stages:
            print(f'START: {stages[n]}    {stages[n].change_datetime} Delta: {stages[n].change_delta}')
            print(' ')
            if n > 0:
                delta = stages[n-1].change_datetime - stages[n].change_datetime
                print(f'{stages[n]}    {stages[n].change_datetime}  for:  {delta}')
                if not stages[n].change_delta:
                    print('Delta Type')
                    print(type(delta))
                    print(f'IF CHANGE DELTA FALSE:{stages[n]} {stages[n].change_delta}')
                    stages[n].change_delta = delta
                    stages[n].save()
                    print(stages[n], stages[n].change_delta)
            n += 1
```